# Помогите правильно указать путь к файлу

Tags: java, javafx

Положил изображение в папку "res", но не получается его подгрузить. При сборке jar файла изображение не отображается. Пытался по всякому указывать путь - не получается. Как правильно?
[image]

Comment: попробуйте указать просто абсолютный файл

Comment: Я думаю абсолютный не получится указать, это изображение должно быть внутри jar файла при компиляции и переносе на другой компьютер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положить файл в папку `resources` и через код можно будет обратиться

```
import java.net.URI;

public class Resource {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "noise.jpg";
//        URI uri = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI();
        URI uri = Resource.class.getResource(fileName).toURI();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создать в src пакет res например и положить в него картинку и получить путь примерно так `Image noiseImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/res/noise.jpg"));`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте или абсолютный путь, или относительный, начиная с папки src: src/res/noise.jpg